# adding array contents to dictionary object in vbscripting

Tags: vbscript

```
   dim a;
   a(0)=migration
   a(1)=blue
    a(2)=syntax
   a(3)=green
    dim d;
set d=createobject(scripting.dictionary)
for i=0 to UBOUND(a)
msgbox a(i)
d.add a(i),a(i+1)
next
```

IN VBSCRIPTING please explain any one why iam getting an "error subscript out of range" to add contents to  dictionary. i have to add array contents to dictionary

Answer (score 2):

Your `Dim a` declares a plain Variant (and initializes it to Empty). Your `a(i)=whatever` (try to) use `a` as an array of variants. Change your code to:

```
>> Dim a(3)
>> a(0)="zero"
>> a(1)="one"
>> a(2)="zwei"
>> a(3)="last of four"
```

(mark the quotes! and the ; not being there at all!) to get an useful fixed array. Then reconsider (and post) how you want the info from tha array transposed into the dictionary - as it is now, the expression `a(i+1)` should throw an error, because there can't be an i + 1 element in `a` when i reaches `UBound(a)`.

Answer (score 1):

[Ekkehard.Horner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16939934/1630171) already pointed out what causes the error (+1), but perhaps a little more explanation is in order.

You have an array with 4 elements:

```
a(0) = "migration"
a(1) = "blue"
a(2) = "syntax"
a(3) = "green"
```

Since VBScript arrays are zero-based, the upper bound of this array is 3. When you iterate over the array in a loop like this:

```
For i = 0 To UBound(a)  'remember: UBound(a) == 3
  d.Add a(i), a(i+1)
Next
```

the unrolled loop does the following:

```
d.Add a(0), a(1)
d.Add a(1), a(2)
d.Add a(2), a(3)
d.Add a(3), a(4)
```

The upper bound of the array is 3, thus trying to access an element at index 4 results in an `subscript out of range` error, which basically means you're trying to access an array index outside the array's boundaries.

If your loop processes the element *after* the current index, you have to stop processing at the *second-last* index, i.e. you need to change your loop into this:

```
For i = 0 To UBound(a)-1
  d.Add a(i), a(i+1)
Next
```